# Как очистить вывод в C++, без system("cls");

Tags: c++

Я смотрел много ответов на этот вопрос, и везде использовалось `system("cls");`, однако мне недавно ответили, что это неправильно. Ещё были ответы с тупым циклом из 27 `\n`.

---

Так как же это сделать грамотно?

Comment: Нет никакого стандартного способа это сделать... Это ос зависимая операция.

Comment: А что тогда принято использовать в таких случаях? Что делать лучше?

Comment: Используйте библиотеку `ncurses`